# Eureka server and eureka client to separate tomcat servers

Tags: spring, tomcat, netflix-eureka

I'm looking for a way to be able to deploy the Eureka server to a different tomcat server than the Eureka client.

this is the client application.yml:

```
eureka:
  client:
    registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 5
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10

server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application.name: my-client
  jmx:
      default-domain: my-client
```

and the server application.yml looks like:

```
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
```

It works perfectly fine if I deploy them to the same tomcat-server. But if I start the tomcat with the server only and later start the server with the client, I get the following error:

```
2017-03-09 16:17:58.496  INFO 7693 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2017-03-09 16:17:58.496  INFO 7693 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2017-03-09 16:17:58.496  INFO 7693 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2017-03-09 16:18:04.740  WARN 7693 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failure with status code 404; retrying on another server if available
2017-03-09 16:18:04.745 ERROR 7693 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MYCLIENT-CLIENT/192.168.196.141:my-client:8080 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
```

What is the difference between bootstrap.yml and application.yml?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your client **application.yml** dosen't have information about where your eureka server is running.client should register with eureka server, for that you need to configure your client **application.yml** as follow

```
eureka:
 client:
  serviceUrl:
       defaultZone:http:localhost:8081/eureka/

 instance:     
  instanceId:application_name:${random.value}
```